# Sending images through php mail function

Tags: php, email

I have a problem sending images through the PHP mail function.

I have used tiny MCE as a text editor for the mail body and pasted some images into the body and some text.

All content with images is displayed as posted data but when I passed it to `mail()` function only the text is sent to the mail address.

I have set the mime version and also the content type to text/HTML in the header.  I don't get what is the actual problem with sending images as content to the mail body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the image path you have in your editor. The image path should be something like

```
Http://www.yoursite.com/images/uploads/image.jpg
```

if it is like

```
../../../images/uploads/image.jpg
```

it won't work in emails.
Try to provide the complete image location.

Comment: ok will check but I copied the image from the disk and pasted it body having tinyMce editor.

so as I think tiny editor creates some different path of image as data.

if i have to resolve is there any other way ??? for tiny editor ??

Thanks a ton

Comment: Thats not the way buddy. Try to insert an Image in your editor Not just copy & paste. and also follow this post http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=642 May help you for sure.